# Find a connected bicubic graph with ten vertices that is not Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory

I suppose there are know algorithms for this problem, but what are some guidelines I could follow?
I know in a Hamiltonian cycle you can't have "threeways"; how can I make a graph that makes it necessary for a cycle to have a threeway?

Comment: @user14111: bicubic means bipartite.

Comment: @user14111: I only meant that a bicubic graph is also bipartite. I agree with your comment that the question makes more sense with cubic instead of bicubic. Perhaps the initial b was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

There are two connected non-isomorphic non-Hamilton cubic graphs on 10 vertices.  I generated the list with `geng` (comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/)), and filtered out the Hamiltonian graphs by writing a script.

[image: The two connected non-Hamilton cubic graphs on 10 vertices]

Neither of these are bipartite.  The first graph has a bridge, and thus cannot be Hamiltonian.  The second one must therefore be the [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph).